# Jenkins master and slave architecture

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins, just wanted to confirm few things.

1. Is jenkins install the agent node by default on the same node when you install the jenkins or it just install the master.
2. Is it good practice to install agent node on same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a simple architecture the master will act as a scheduler and executor ( **agent** and **server** ).

On master / slave architecture, the master can act as scheduler and / or executor meanwhile the slaves will act as executors.

You have first to decide why are you trying to go with a master / slave architecure ? This will make you benefit from :

1- Parallel jobs execution with workload distribution against the slaves.

2- Benefits on computation resources from slave nodes.

3- Separate executors for multiple environments ( Prod, Qa ...) using labels.

4- Benefit of different Operative Systems that will make all the needed building tools available for your jobs ( Compatibility ).

So for me, i don't see any benefit of installing both on the same server unless maybe for **labelling purpose** so you can assign different resources for **jobs queuing** for every environment as an example ( see point 3 ).